# localStorage issue when doing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

I have some simple code that will run to check Internet connectivity and I'm using `localStorage` to hold the variable value and yet when I run it the value of that variable isn't effected. So, what can I do to fix it. Please help. If the state is changed to `true` the submit will happen else otherwise it will be prevented.

```
localStorage.setItem("state","");

function checkConnection(){             
   $.ajax({
       url:"assets/ping.js",
       success:function(res){
            localStorage.setItem("state","true");
       },
       onerror:function(){
            localStorage.setItem("state","false");
       } 
   });
 }

$("form").submit(function(e){

   checkConnection();

   if(localStorage.getItem("state") == "false"){
        return false;
   } else if(localStorage.getItem("state") == "true") {
        return true;
   }

});
```

Comment: when I click submit the value of state stays an empty string it doesnt change but the request happend

Comment: `onerror:` should be `error:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sychronization isssue. Your API call to check the connection does not complete before the form is submitted. You want the AJAX call to block until it gets a response. (actually I guess it should be called SJAX for synchronous).

You have to add `async` is `false` to the settings parameter.
Read: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Here is how you do that with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"assets/ping.js",
   async: false
   success:function(res){
       localStorage.setItem("state", "true");
   },
   error: function(){
        localStorage.setItem("state","false");
   }           
});
```

Also note that the error handler should be under `error` not `onerror`.

Finally, if all you are trying to do is detect if the Internet connection was lost you can do that on most browsers by checking the value of window.navigator.onLine. See: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#browser-state

Comment: thanks it's working fine there was a simple thing to add to check connectivity you shouldnt call a javascript file from the server you should call a server side lang like php also the php file respond with json format so I added dataType :"json" and its fine thank you so much!